# Youtube analytics api real time

Tags: php, google-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I am building the Youtube web application using Youtube API.
At the moment I need real-time analytics for the clips(videos).
However, I couldn't find any info in the document.
I can get some info using videos' statics.
But, the view count not updated until someone clicks like/dislike or put the comment.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I am using google/apiclient package to get analytics. It works fine for 2 or more days before. However I can't get any real-time data using this api. So I using video's list with statics part in Youtube Data V3 api. It returns some basic analytics, but the view_count not update eventhough I was waiting for couple of hours. So I click the like button on the youtube and retry, now view_count changed. Any clue for this?

Comment: What makes you think that there is a real-time youtube analytics api?

Answer (score 2):

There is no Real-time YouTube analytics api.

Data returned by the YouTube analytics api can take up to 48 hours to be processed.  Its best wait at least 48 hours before you request data. Any results under 48 hours old that you may see if you see anything at all would not be stable.